# How do I access the second attribute of an html file?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project and I have encountered a problem. The HTML file that I want to parse has two of the same attribute. I know if I want to access an attribute I would have to type .(name of attribute). But what do I do when I have two?

```
<h2 id="jojo-39-s-bizarre-adventure"> 
<span class="item-num">7 </span> 
<span>Jojo's Bizarre Adventure</span> 
</h2>
```

As you can see, there are two "span" and I would like to access the second one

I have set that piece of code in a variable "i" but I can't do i.span because that gives me the first one. I have no idea on how to access the second "span" attribute.

Comment: Have you tried my answer/solution ?

Answer (score 0):

With this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//span[2]
```

Or this [css](/questions/tagged/css) selector:

```
span:nth-child(2)
```

you can retrieve second `span` element:

```
Jojo's Bizarre Adventure
```

Let's try in Python `requests` + `lxml`:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

res = requests.get(
    'https://sputnick.fr/downloads/how-do-i-access-the-second-attribute-of-an-html-file.html'
)

doc = html.fromstring(res.text)

# Using XPath:
print(doc.xpath('//span[2]')[0].text)

# Using CSS:
print(doc.cssselect('span:nth-child(2)')[0].text)
```